# Site search only works on homepage

Tags: html, asp.net, forms, web

I have this issue:

On this site http://www.va.gov/OSDBU/index.asp if you scroll to the middle of the page and look on the right sidebar you will see a field titled, "Search VA OSDBU" and when I search it brings up results, great.

Now for the issue, this site search appears on every page of the web site however if I'm on another page, let's say this one, http://www.va.gov/osdbu/library/factsheets.asp, and I try to search for something the result is a page not found.

How can I make it work on every page? Do I need to change something in the form action?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the correct path to `site_search.asp` for the form on every page. Currently, each search form is looking for `site_search.asp` in that pages current directory.

**Update:**

You need to change this:

```
<form name="SearchForm" action="site_search.asp" method="get">
```

to this:

```
<form name="SearchForm" action="http://www.va.gov/OSDBU/site_search.asp" method="get">
```

Comment: thanks for your response. The site is built using a CMS called Teamsite and so this search box is in a file called admin-right-col.htm and I can only edit it from that file not on every page. I cannot edit on every single page. Does that make sense? thanks

Comment: Correct. See my update for further explanation. I'd recommend reading up on relative vs absolute paths.

Comment: I tried entering the entire url earlier and i left the http:// part off. I know it's discouraged to leave a comment thanking you but you my friend are brilliant and I salute you for your help. Works perfectly!